# Run a process in background from a unix sh script

Tags: unix, scripting, background, sh

Ok, my first question so sorry for any errors in the way I've asked.

I am trying to create a script jenkins.sh which should call/launch another process (`start_rhino.sh`) in the background (if started normally it will take over the console and will not free the command line unless it is stopped).

So far I have tried:

`./start-rhino.sh &`             -> starts the process the same as `./start-rhino.sh`

`nohup ./start-rhino.sh &`       -> Requires a key press to continue

and none of them immediately released the command line in order for the script to progress. In desperation I also tried with double && and /& but with no success. I think the nohup worked the best but it required an 'enter' key press in order to continue to command line (I've tried them directly from command line not by running the script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nohup ./start-rhino.sh < /dev/null 2>&1 > /dev/null &`

Comment: I tried it but when I run the initial script 'jenkins.sh' and it says "nohup: redirecting stderr to stdout" and then nothing more happens. The script hangs and doesn't progress anymore. Is there a special way to write the command to be properly ran from a sh file?

Comment: What does `start-rhino.sh` do? You say it requires a key press. What is waiting for the keypress? Is it the script, or is it something in that script?

Comment: 'start-rhino.sh' Starts a server application. When I said that nohup requires a key-press I meant that when using it it wouldn't release the command line immediately but it required a key press in order for the command line prompt to appear. Sorry I'm so lousy with the explications.

Comment: Yes, but that means that *something* is waiting for the keypress. What is waiting? Is it the "server application", or is it something in your script?

Comment: well nothing... In my script there are no user inputs... and rhino-start.sh doesn't ask for anything... I even searched https://developer.opencloud.com/devportal/display/OCDEV/Rhino+2.3 for some official information but nothing... Thanks for your help. I'll try to emulate ctrl+Z from the script. Do you know how could I do that?

Comment: Why do you think control-Z would help in any way?  All that does is send a SIGTSTP signal to the process. What does that have to do with making it not wait for a keystroke?

Comment: I was trying to start it in front and send it to background manually. But it works now with your command. Works great actually which kind of worries me why it didn't work yesterday. Thank you for your help. I would Up-vote your answer but I still don;t have the necessary reputation.